# Apache Per-user web directories under user's own ID instead of www-data?

Tags: apache-2.4, user-permissions, ubuntu-14.04, setuid, users

Talking about this feature
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/public_html.html

Is there a way (HOW?) to have Apache take on (setuid) the ID of each "~user", instead of doing everything under the www-data userid?

There is a related question here:
[Apache per user permissions](https://serverfault.com/questions/478321/apache-per-user-permissions)

In that question, one answer actually advises against doing what I'm asking:

> If you were to run one apache instance for each user, and have that
>   apache owned by the user, you'd thereby grant apache permissions to
>   write to all of the user's directories. That's generally not
>   considered a good idea at all.

The fact that the answerer stated that you SHOULD NOT do this,  seems to imply that you CAN do it. So now I'm just asking HOW TO do it, because I have a very specific use-case that requires it, but running a separate instance for each userid is too resource-intensive. So, is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try Apache [ITK MPM](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/). It works like the traditional Apache prefork model, but assigns a different UID for each virtual host. And if you use Apache 2.4, you can use mod_rewrite to make `~/` paths to use the UID of that particular homedir as instructed by ITK MPM home page.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /~([a-z]+)/ - [E=ITKUID:$1]
AssignUserIDExpr %{reqenv:ITKUID}
```

Comment: Note that this is effectively doing what OP doesn't want to do: Run a separate instance of Apache for each user. ITK MPM automates that task, but it does have slightly higher resource usage than other execution models, including traditional prefork. That said, I doubt resource usage will be an issue in any of these use cases we're talking about, including ITK or running separate instances; for most users, even prefork works fine. But, OP just wants automated handling of switching users when using mod_userdir, which is easily accomplished with SuExec; no new and experimental modules needed.

Comment: suEXEC makes only cgi-scripts run under uid $foo rights, mpm-itk serves everything with uid $foo.

Comment: Ah, yes, if OP wants Apache to also read files as a different UID, you're correct. I can't think of many reasons to do that (because Apache can be in the group of many users, so permissions can be setup quite strongly), but your solution does provide that at a small resource usage penalty. Also, to be clear, suexec doesn't have to be limited to CGI; mod_fcgid also works with suexec, providing a nice/fast/efficient way to run PHP and other apps as a speficied UID without the performance and resource problems of CGI.

Comment: Maybe OP will let us know what he's trying to accomplish with this and it'll make it more clear what the right solution is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would enable SuExec.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html

Specifically, the section that begins **Using suEXEC**.

Quoted here for convenience:

> **Using suEXEC**
>
> Requests for CGI programs will call the suEXEC wrapper only if they
>   are for a virtual host containing a 'SuexecUserGroup' directive or if
>   they are processed by 'mod_userdir'.
>
> Virtual Hosts: One way to use the suEXEC wrapper is through the
>   'SuexecUserGroup' directive in 'VirtualHost' definitions. By setting
>   this directive to values different from the main server user ID, all
>   requests for CGI resources will be executed as the User and Group
>   defined for that ''. If this directive is not specified
>   for a '' then the main server userid is assumed.
>
> User directories: Requests that are processed by 'mod_userdir' will
>   call the suEXEC wrapper to execute CGI programs under the userid of
>   the requested user directory. The only requirement needed for this
>   feature to work is for CGI execution to be enabled for the user and
>   that the script must meet the scrutiny of the security checks above.
>   See also the '--with-suexec-userdir' compile time option.

You'll need to insure the  ['--with-suexec-userdir'](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/suexec.html#install) compile time option is enabled in your Apache build.